# r Evaluate condition by group in data.table to filter rows, data structure: list of data.tables

Tags: r, filter, data.table

Another quick data.table question related to a list of data.tables:

```
foo <- rep(1:3, times=3)
lorem <- c(20, 30, -10, 405, 70, 20, 35, 50, 30)
df1 <- data.table(foo, lorem)

foo1 <- rep(1:3, times=3)
lorem1 <- c(0, 30, -50, 500, 20, 10, 500, 20, 10)
df2 <- data.table(foo1, lorem1)
setnames(df2, 1:2,c("foo", "lorem"))

df.list <- list(df1, df2)
print(df.list)

[[1]]
   foo lorem
1:   1    20
2:   2    30
3:   3   -10
4:   1   405
5:   2    70
6:   3    20
7:   1    35
8:   2    50
9:   3    30

[[2]]
   foo lorem
1:   1     0
2:   2    30
3:   3   -50
4:   1   500
5:   2    20
6:   3    10
7:   1   500
8:   2    20
9:   3    10
```

I am trying to drop all observations where variations within the lorem column exceed 20x or are negative.

So for instance, for foo == 1 (my id column), his variation would be larger than 20, since of the values (20, 405, 35), (max = 405 / min = 20) > 20.

This is complicated by the fact that I have to run this on a list of 40 data.tables.

I tried to run the following:

```
> tester <- purrr::map(df.list, function(dat) {
    + dat[dat[, .I[which.max(lorem) / which.min(lorem) < 20], by=foo]$V1]
    + })
    > 
    > print(tester)
    [[1]]
       foo lorem
    1:   1    20
    2:   1   405
    3:   1    35
    4:   2    30
    5:   2    70
    6:   2    50
    7:   3   -10
    8:   3    20
    9:   3    30

    [[2]]
       foo lorem
    1:   1     0
    2:   1   500
    3:   1   500
    4:   2    30
    5:   2    20
    6:   2    20
    7:   3   -50
    8:   3    10
    9:   3    10
```

But as you can see this only sorted the list by id. Not too familiar with the .I / .SD subsetting that data.table uses. How could I approach this problem to get the following output:

```
[[1]]
       foo lorem
       2    30
       2    70
       2    50


[[2]]
       foo lorem
       2    30
       2    20
       2    20
```

So I keep only those rows where max(lorem) / min(lorem) < 20 or are non-negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looping over the `list` with `lapply`, create logical expression with `max` and `min` and check if `all` the values are non-negative, grouped by 'foo', then extract the row index (`.I`) to subset the rows of the dataset

```
lapply(df.list, function(dat) dat[dat[,  
   .I[all(sign(lorem) >=0) &&(max(lorem) <= 20 * min(lorem))], foo]$V1])
#[[1]]
#   foo lorem
#1:   2    30
#2:   2    70
#3:   2    50

#[[2]]
#   foo lorem
#1:   2    30
#2:   2    20
#3:   2    20
```

---

If we are using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(df.list, ~ .x[.x[, .I[all(sign(lorem) >= 0) &&
          (max(lorem) <= 20 * min(lorem))], foo]$V1])
```

Comment: The sign issue can be checked using the min, eg, `rbindlist(df.list, id="tab")[, if (((mn <- min(lorem)) >= 0) && max(lorem) <= 20*mn) .SD, by=.(tab, foo)]`

Comment: Uf am I happy you're around on stackoverflow! @akrun!! :) Really appreciate your help with all my questions. I'm conducting research in  Economics and Psychology but slowly regret not having taken more comp scie classes ^^ thanks for helping out again!

Comment: Hi akrun, yeah, I made the new account for use at work (since I don't want to log in from there now)